# What are the rules of algebra within a real and complex functions $\Re(\cdot)$ and $\Im(\cdot)$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a problem of the form $\Re(1 - G(s)^2) \ge 0$, where $G(s)$ is a transfer function. What type of algebraic manipulation can take place within the $\Re(\cdot)$ function. Do properties like homogeneity and additivity apply within $\Re(\cdot)$?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Whatever manipulations you can normally make with an expression can always be made inside the arguments of a function. For example, you can write $\mathfrak{R}\left(1 - G(s)^2\right) = \mathfrak{R}\left((1 - G(s))(1 + G(s))\right)$. But you cannot rewrite it as $\mathfrak{R}\left(1 - G(s)\right) \mathfrak{R}\left(1 + G(s)\right)$, since that would no longer stay inside the function.

Comment: Let $G$ have real and imaginary parts $A,\,B$, so your problem is equivalent to $A^2-B^2\le1$, i.e. $\Re^2G-\Im^2G\le1$. I don't think you can do it any neater way than that.

Comment: $\Re(G(s)^2) \le 1 $ is the result I initially arrived at. Can you refer me to books and articles for this? Thanks

Comment: You should make it more concrete, what is your $G$. Your function is probably analytic, on what domain do you have this restriction, $U= \{ z,\Re(1-z^2)> 0\}$ is an open set, to draw it, draw $\Re(1-z) > 0$ and take its square root.

Comment: I need a solution that applies to any $G(s)$, so I can't be more specific. I am working in the Laplace domain. I want to know if $\Re{(1-G(s)^2)} \ge 0$ is equivalent to $\Re{(1)} \ge \Re{(G(s)^2)}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The function $\Re:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb R$ linear, but obviously not $\mathbb C$ linear.

It is also not multiplicative for general complex inputs: $\Re(i)=0$ but $\Re(i^2)=-1$.  But it is elementary to check that $\Re (z^2)=\Re(z)^2-\Im(z)^2$ (or you could even work it out for $\Re(z_1z_2)$ if you really want.)

I don't know anything about transfer functions, though, so I don't know if this gets you any closer to evaluating the expression than $1\geq \Re(G(s)^2)$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. $\Re(G(s)^2) \le 1 $ is the result I initially arrived at. I was not sure the algebra would allow that. can you refer me to any books or articles dealing with such algebra

Comment: I couldn't say what book would have it. It's a trivial observation that probably gets remarked on in passing but not emphasized.

Comment: Is there any insight at all into $\Re (G(s))$?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with transfer functions, the complex variable $ s $ is mostly represented as $ s = -\sigma + j\omega $ where $ \sigma $ has the interpretation of damping, and $ \omega $ of angular frequency of the system.
Let us assume that the transfer function $ \mathrm{G}(s) $ is in the form:
$$ \mathrm{G}(s) = a(\sigma,\omega) + jb(\sigma,\omega) $$
After squearing we get:
$$ \mathrm{G}^2(s) = a^2(\sigma,\omega) +j2a(\sigma,\omega)b(\sigma,\omega)  - b^2(\sigma,\omega) $$
Then we get:
$$ \Re\{1-\mathrm{G}^2(s)\} = \Re\{1 - a^2(\sigma,\omega) -j2a(\sigma,\omega)b(\sigma,\omega)  + b^2(\sigma,\omega)\} = 1 - a^2(\sigma,\omega) + b^2(\sigma,\omega) $$
$$ 1 \geq  a^2(\sigma,\omega) - b^2(\sigma,\omega) $$
Depanding on the values of $ \sigma $ or $ \omega $ your condition gives you the possible values (it will be a region of values due to the inequality) for the other one.